# Vim way to yank text object on multiple lines

Tags: vim

Suppose I have

```
- 'autoindent' is set by default
- 'autoread' is set by default
- 'backspace' defaults to "indent,eol,start"
- 'backupdir' defaults to .,~/.local/share/nvim/backup (|xdg|)
- 'complete' doesn't include "i"
- 'directory' defaults to ~/.local/share/nvim/swap// (|xdg|), auto-created
```

How can I yank words `autoindent autoread backspace...` and so on to system register with visual block (suppose)

P.S. have tried vim-multiple-cursors, but that plugin [buggy](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors/issues/212) (and not vim way) and dont allow copy-paste if one exit multiple-cursors mode in between.

---

[***Great answers too in russian version***](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/603697/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%B2-vim#603724)

Comment: i don't have a super elegant solution to this, but i usually just do something wherein i fully copy the lines and then whittle each one down using a macro. (in this case, the macro might look like: `^dwxEDj`). from there, block select is straightforward.

Comment: @acushner yep, that not what I look for, but thanks

Comment: [One of answers](http://superuser.com/questions/818290/select-all-matching-text-in-vim/818607#818607), thanks to cronfy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My [ExtractMatches plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4795) has (among others) a `:YankMatches` command for that. It works similar to the built-in `:substitute`:

```
:YankMatches!/'\zs[^']\+\ze'/+
```

By default, the command separates the elements by a newline; if you want them space-separated, use this variation:

```
:YankMatches!/'\zs[^']\+\ze'/& /+
```

Comment: Maybe I have bug when I try to yank text above with last search: first I search with command `\v'\zs[^']+\ze'`, then I try yank with space separator `YankMatches!//& /+` and now I have text without separation at all `autoindentautoreadbackspacebackupdircompletedirectory`

Comment: @bjornmelgaard: Good observation! That was a bad interaction of magic-modifiers (`\v`) and `\zs`. It works when you move the former after the latter: `'\zs\v[^']+\ze'` (or avoid using `\v` at all). I've just published a new version 1.40 of the plugin (that also requires ingo-library 1.029) that handles this, too.

Comment: yahoo, great plugin by the way, [I use it like this for now](https://github.com/BjornMelgaard/dotfiles/blob/master/nvim/init.vim#L251-L258), here I have tried to make your plugin yank (and delete) highlighted text, maybe I will make plugin (or you, if you want, because maybe I will switch to kakoune, dunno) that will provide "highlight" (or match) text object. For example: ym - yank highlighted, "+ym - to clipboard, dm - delete, "+dm - ..., yM - yank all except, dM - delete all except =) What you think?

Comment: @bjornmelgaard: Thanks for sharing that. To yank a single highlighted match, you can just do `ygn`; I don't see much use for yanking _all_ matches, there usualy would be lots of duplicates, right?

Answer (score 6):

### One method

```
:%norm f'"Zya'
```

would put `'autoindent' 'autoread' 'backspace' 'backupdir' 'complete' 'directory'` in register `z`.

[image: method 1]

To make it available outside of Vim you can do:

```
:let @+ = @z
```

### Another one with the same result but a lot more complicated (just for the fun of it)

```
/'\w\{-}' <CR>
"Zca'
<C-r><C-o>"<Esc>
n.n.n.n.n.
```

[image: method 2]

### Bonus

The quickest way to clear a named register (register z, here) is:

```
qzq
```

Comment: Its second best answer I have ever seen, but too not as good as yank with multiple-cursors if it had worked, but if I will pick, I'll pick that

Answer (score 1):

In order to make it work:

1. empty the register `a`:  typing

`qaq` in normal mode

2. execute in command line :

   `:%s/^- '\(\w\+\)'/\=setreg('A',submatch(1),'V')/n`
3. the desired output is copied in register `a` and you can get it by typing in command line :

`:put A`

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/818290/select-all-matching-text-in-vim/818607#818607

Comment: currently I think best solution is to use [vim-multiple-cursors and this command](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors/issues/212), but it didnt work on my editor, but maybe it will on your, please reply is it)

Comment: one second I will see

Comment: for the second one it will not work because the problem is the words doesn't not have the same length. I will check the first one

Comment: It looks like you use visual-block, and not vim-multiple-cursors plugin, because `<C-v>{range}j<C-n>ve` select words as expected, it just dont copy to register

Comment: I have update my answer which works great based on your first comment. You are totally correct I did not pay attention to that thanks a lot.

Comment: you just paste post of another man and didnt answer is vim-multiple-cursors work on your editor

Comment: I don't want to use the plugin as it will affect some of my completion using c-n

Comment: ok​
  ​
  ​​
  ​
  ​
  ​
  
  ​
  ​
  ​
  ​
  ​
  ​
  ​
  ​
  ​

Answer (score 1):

A solution without visual block:

`:let @+=''` - clear the system register

`qa` - record to register 'a'

`^3l"kyej` - go fourth column, yank the word to register 'k' and go to the next line

`:let @+=@+ . ' ' . @k`   - concatenate the system register, ' ' and register 'k' and store the result again in the system register

`q` - stop recording

`5@a` - repeat the recorded command 5 times - voila

`reg +` - shows `"+ autoindent autoread backspace backupdir complete`

Comment: It`s best solution I have seen, but complex as others, do you know why ['vim-multiple-cursors'](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors/issues/212) solution don't work, I currently try to find that with Julio Batista